# debugging workers with sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, sidekiq

I converted from resque to sidekiq gem for my ruby on rails app to have less memory usage and faster response times.

The problem:

- one of my workers has an error and unlike resque-web the sidekiq-web does not show full details on the error ( like line number and cause of error )
- I'm unable to properly debug my workers, is there a workaround for this? In terminal I just get something like

error:

```
  2012-07-12T13:26:19Z 64455 TID-ousyenaqg WARN: undefined method `perform' for #<BookInit:0x007f8c6f73f520>
```

More precise errors are a must have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try change

```
def self.perform(params...)
```

to

```
def perform(params...)
```

Comment: Yes I found it out already, missed that one ;) it works fine with this correction

Comment: +1 How did you know he was defining a static method?

Answer (score 2):

Add the next code to a rake task, and then debug it like you used to do with resque

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/cli'

desc 'Runs Sidekiq as a rake task'
task :debug_sidekiq => :environment do
  begin
    cli = Sidekiq::CLI.instance
    cli.parse
    cli.run
  rescue => e
    raise e if $DEBUG
    STDERR.puts e.message
    STDERR.puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
    exit 1
  end
end
```

The code is taken from sidekiq/bin/sidekiq

Answer (score 1):

**Debugging Sidekiq With Pry :**

Normally, the Sidekiq server will not start Pry when executing the statements.

You can use [Sidekiq inline infrastructure](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/testing/inline.rb) for debugging Sidekiq with pry:

*The Sidekiq inline infrastructure overrides perform_async and it
actually calls **perform** instead of **perform_async**. This allows workers to be run inline in a
testing environment.*

You need to add the following to your code :

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'
```

Now Pry will be able to call the perform method.

**Note** : This won't help you if you have to run jobs in threaded environment to test concurrency or performance.